# Visual Web Developer Express, how to run SQL to a new database

Tags: asp.net, visual-web-developer

How do I run a DDL-SQL to create tables on a newly created database in [Visual Web Developer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Included_products) 2010?

New to the ASP.NET world, I'm trying to insert the ddl to build the [Northwind database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwind).

I've tried the trick of inserting the SQL from a query-view, but SQL Server Express Edition crashes :-)

(Hello Microsoft, long time, no see...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download MS [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio#Express_Edition) (it's free). With this tool managing SQL Server databases is a lot easier.

Edit (answer to the comment below),

It doesn't work that way :) SQL Server has two authentication methods: Windows authentication and its own (user and password). First you need to use Windows authentication to log in and you can do whatever you want, for example change the sa (server administrator) password.

Comment: Ah, thanks. :-) Now what's the user/pwd? Never set. Tried sa/blank - no luck.

Comment: ah, thanks again. Haven't used mssql since 6.5, need to catch up some bits... Regards, /t